# What is the right way of showing data from a DB, but not on a gridview

Tags: asp.net

The title is not informative enough, couldn't come up with something that will fit, so I will appreciate if someone will change it, or at least offer another one.

My question:

I have a page that shows a user's profile by his ID: (Consider the next page as an example)

[image]

In the above, there are 3 fields which are dynamic:

1. The user's name
2. The skin he is using
3. His profile image

I don't want to add labels around the whole page, and set them before the page loads, in order to present his info (there will be more fields).

I want something that will be easy to maintain for future changes.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks, Guy

Comment: what you mean by "don't want to add labels around the whole page"??and why you don't want to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this code.

```
public void UserProfile(DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {              
                String sr = string.Empty;
                sr += "<html><body><table>";                               
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
                    {
                        sr += "<tr>";
                        for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            sr += "<td>";
                            sr += table.Columns[j].ColumnName;
                            sr += "</td>";


                            sr += "<td>";
                            sr += row.ItemArray[j];
                            sr += "</td>";
                        }
                        sr += "</tr>";                       
                    }
                }
                sr += "</table></body></html>";
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal ltr = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal();
                ltr.Text = sr;
                this.Controls.Add(ltr);            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Hope This helps.